# passing the data to a destination view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, core-location

I am actually using core location along with map kit framework to get the user location on a button's click. I have two view controllers. The first one is a normal view controller with the map view and all the core location processes done in it along with reverse geo coding. 
The second one is a table view controller that displays the obtained data from geo coding and location's latitude and longitude.

The problem which I get is that I am not able to pass the information of the current location to the next view. But, I can pass my geo coding values. It seems strange for me and any help would be much appreciated.

```
mapViewController.m

#import "mapViewController.h"

@interface mapViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
    addressViewController *view;
}

@end

@implementation mapViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    self.addressOutlet.enabled = NO;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addressSegue"])
    {
        view= segue.destinationViewController;

         // assigning the addressPlacemark the same value as the current placemark
        view.addressPlacemark = placemark;

        NSLog(@"this is perfectly executed");

    }
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 600, 600);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newOne = [locations lastObject];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"the new location is : %@", newOne);
    NSLog(@"the latitude is %f", newOne.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"the speed is %.2f mps", newOne.speed);
    NSLog(@"at time : %@",newOne.timestamp);

//These 4 NSLog statements are returning the outputs as expected


 [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newOne completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"the current city is %@",placemark.locality);

        self.addressOutlet.enabled = YES;
        // view.currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]init];

        view.currentLocation = newOne;  // assigning currentLocation the same location as the newOne

        NSLog(@"the currentLocation object has the location : \n %@",view.currentLocation);
        //problem : the output of this NSLog gives Null
    }];

}
```

Comment: What you have tried? There are tons of this questions. Google it!

Comment: `Xcode` tag should only be used for questions about the Xcode tool, itself, not for programming questions for which you happen be using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in

```
view.currentLocation = newOne;
```

In this context **view** is nil. view is instantiated when **prepareForSegue:** is getting called. So what you can do is

```
tempLocation = newOne; // Store newOne in a temporary variable
```

and in

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addressSegue"])
{
    view= segue.destinationViewController;

     // assigning the addressPlacemark the same value as the current placemark
    view.addressPlacemark = placemark;
     view.currentLocation = tempLocation;
    NSLog(@"this is perfectly executed");

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anil :) It worked.. A simple and perfect solution.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not save `addressViewController` in current controller because it retain him till you perform segue again. And in some point of execution it will be at least useless or even harmful.
2. `view.currentLocation = newOne;  // assigning currentLocation the same location as the newOne`
   view at this point can contain nill, so any assigns to it's properties do not correct. You should save `currentLocation` in current view controller's property and then in `prepareForSegue` set it to `destinationViewController`.
3. I don't want to talk about your code naming convention, but it confused me when I saw class name which start from lower case letter=)

Comment: I understand @Ossir for the naming convention. I am going to change them completely as you have mentioned. I followed them like properties which I shouldn't have done. Thanks for pointing that out. Why did not I realise it earlier. And, I am new to programming and hence these errors :(